# How to fetch the Response object of a Request synchronously on Scrapy?

Tags: python, scrapy

I believe using "callback" method is asynchronous, please correct me if I'm wrong. I'm still new with Python so please bear with me.

Anyway, I'm trying to make a method to check if a file exists and here is my code:

```
def file_exists(self, url):
    res = False;
    response = Request(url, method='HEAD', dont_filter=True)
    if response.status == 200:
        res = True
    return res
```

I thought the Request() method will return a Response object but it still returns a Request object, to capture the Response, I have to create a different method for the callback.

Is there a way to get the Response object within the code block where you call the Response() method?

Comment: You may want to try https://github.com/rolando/scrapy-inline-requests

Answer (score 4, accepted):

`Request` objects don't generate anything.

Scrapy uses asynchronous Downloader engine which takes these `Request` objects and generate `Response` objects.

if any method in your spider returns a Request object it is automatically scheduled in the downloader and returns a `Response` object to specified `callback`(i.e. `Request(url, callback=self.my_callback)`). 
Check out more at [scrapy's architecture overview](http://doc.scrapy.org/en/latest/topics/architecture.html?highlight=architecture)

Now depends when and where you are doing it you can schedule requests by telling the downloader to schedule some requests:

```
self.crawler.engine.schedule(Request(url, callback=self.my_callback), spider)
```

If you run this from a spider `spider` here can most likely be `self` here and self.crawler is inherited from `scrapy.Spider`.

Alternatively you can always block asynchronous stack by using something like `requests` like:

```
def parse(self, response):
    image_url = response.xpath('//img/@href').extract_first()
    if image_url:
        image_head = requests.head(image_url)
        if 'image' in image_head.headers['Content-Type']:
            item['image'] = image_url
```

It will slow your spider down but it's significantly easier to implement and manage.

Comment: I just want to check if the files exists, I'm not really going to download the files. My crawler will check all of the pages and verify all of the files like images and downloadables(doc, pdf, etc.), those missing files will be added to an array field of my Item object named "missing_files[]".

Comment: Well you have everything you need up there in my answer then :)

Comment: Yeah, I just used requests.head(). Thanks!

Answer (score 7):

If anyone is still interested in a possible solution – I managed it by doing a request with "requests" sort of "inside" a scrapy function like this:

```
import requests    
request_object = requests.get(the_url_you_like_to_get)
response_object = scrapy.Selector(request_object )
item['attribute'] = response_object .xpath('//path/you/like/to/get/text()').extract_first()
```

and then proceed.

Comment: Some simple introduction about the context of the xpath usage might show better how your answer help the question.

Comment: Still useful for old version like 1.5 in my case.

Comment: + I need to add something to this solution because I experienced this right now and got issues. Using `requests.get("http://url.com")` forgets the cookies. For instance if you need to login to obtain what you want to scrape, you loose the cookie session and this is as if you did not login. You should use [Request objects](https://docs.scrapy.org/en/latest/topics/request-response.html) to conserve it or try to implement [cookies](https://docs.python-requests.org/en/master/user/quickstart/#cookies) in `requests.get()`.

Answer (score -1):

Scrapy uses Request and Response objects for crawling web sites.

Typically, Request objects are generated in the spiders and pass across the system until they reach the Downloader, which executes the request and returns a Response object which travels back to the spider that issued the request.

Unless you are manually using a Downloader, it seems like the way you're using the framework is incorrect. I'd read a bit more about how you can create proper spiders [here](http://doc.scrapy.org/en/latest/topics/spiders.html).

As for file exists, your spider can store relevant information in a database or other data structure when parsing the scraped data in its parse*() method, and you can later query it in your own code.